# How to open/save multiple pdf pages with jspdf and html2canvas package?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, async-await, jspdf, html2canvas

I'm struggling to save/open in a new tab a pdf document with more than one page. It works fine with only one page, but with more than one, it doens't work. I did it with `for` loop but somehow in the pdf document always  appears just the first page. I use this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jspdf-html2canvas?activeTab=readme

Can you tell me why doesn't work with the for loop? It doesn't matter how much page I have, for example in the success function defined action is called only once and only one function. If I remove the comment by the `window.open(pdf.output('bloburl'))`, then the `addPage()` function isn't called. Also the addPage just add empty pages to the `jsPD` object, also 4 pages instead of 3.

Thanks in advance!

Here is the code:

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
const pages = document.querySelectorAll('.page');
btn.addEventListener('click', async () => {
    let jsPD = new jsPDF();

    // one page
    // html2PDF(pages, {
    //     jsPDF: {
    //         format: 'a4',
    //         dpi: 400,
    //     },
    //     imageType: 'image/jpeg',
    //     output: 'my.pdf',
    //     html2canvas: {
    //         scrollX: 0,
    //         scrollY: -window.scrollY,
    //         scale: 5,
    //         dpi: 400,
    //         quality: 4,
    //     }, margin: {
    //         top: 24,
    //         right: 24,
    //         bottom: 24,
    //         left: 24,
    //     },
    //     success: function (pdf) {
    //         // pdf.save(this.output)
    //         window.open(pdf.output('bloburl'))
    //     }
    // });


    // more page version
    for await (const page of pages) {
        console.log(page)
        const pdf = await html2PDF(page, {
            jsPDF: {
                format: 'a4',
                dpi: 400,
            },
            imageType: 'image/jpeg',
            output: 'my.pdf',
            html2canvas: {
                scrollX: 0,
                scrollY: -window.scrollY,
                scale: 5,
                dpi: 400,
                quality: 4,
            }, margin: {
                top: 24,
                right: 24,
                bottom: 24,
                left: 24,
            },
            success: function (pdf) {
                // pdf.save(this.output)
                // window.open(pdf.output('bloburl'))
                jsPD.addPage(pdf.output())
            }
        });
    }

    window.open(jsPD.output('bloburl'))

});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<button id="btn">Generate</button>
<div class="page" style="width: 210mm;color: black;background: white; margin: 0 auto">
    <div class="">
        <h3 style="margin: 0">PDF for Test</h3>
        <img src="assets/img2.jpg" style="max-width: 100%" alt="">
        <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam cupiditate dolores est,
            pariatur perferendis
            quia quis quos recusandae similique veritatis Ad delectus doloremque est fugit id molestias nesciunt, qui
            tenetur?
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="break-before">
        <p style="margin: 0">Here is some content for testing!!</p>
        <h3>PDF for Test</h3>
        <img src="assets/img2.jpg" style="max-width: 100%" alt="">
        <p style="margin: 0">Here is some content for testing!!</p>
        <h3 style="margin: 0">PDF for Test</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="break-before">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam cupiditate dolores est,
        pariatur perferendis
        quia quis quos recusandae similique veritatis! Ad delectus doloremque est fugit id molestias nesciunt, qui
        tenetur?
    </div>
</div>

<div class="page" style="width: 210mm;color: black;background: white; margin: 0 auto">
    <div class="">
        <h3 style="margin: 0">PDF for Test</h3>
        <img src="assets/img2.jpg" style="max-width: 100%" alt="">
        <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam cupiditate dolores est,
            pariatur perferendis
            quia quis quos recusandae similique veritatis Ad delectus doloremque est fugit id molestias nesciunt, qui
            tenetur?
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="break-before">
        <p style="margin: 0">Here is some content for testing!!</p>
        <h3>PDF for Test</h3>
        <img src="assets/img2.jpg" style="max-width: 100%" alt="">
        <p style="margin: 0">Here is some content for testing!!</p>
        <h3 style="margin: 0">PDF for Test</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="break-before">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam cupiditate dolores est,
        pariatur perferendis
        quia quis quos recusandae similique veritatis! Ad delectus doloremque est fugit id molestias nesciunt, qui
        tenetur?
    </div>
</div>

<div class="page" style="width: 210mm;color: black;background: white; margin: 0 auto">
    <div class="">
        <h3 style="margin: 0">PDF for Test</h3>
        <img src="assets/img2.jpg" style="max-width: 100%" alt="">
        <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam cupiditate dolores est,
            pariatur perferendis
            quia quis quos recusandae similique veritatis Ad delectus doloremque est fugit id molestias nesciunt, qui
            tenetur?
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="break-before">
        <p style="margin: 0">Here is some content for testing!!</p>
        <h3>PDF for Test</h3>
        <img src="assets/img2.jpg" style="max-width: 100%" alt="">
        <p style="margin: 0">Here is some content for testing!!</p>
        <h3 style="margin: 0">PDF for Test</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="break-before">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam cupiditate dolores est,
        pariatur perferendis
        quia quis quos recusandae similique veritatis! Ad delectus doloremque est fugit id molestias nesciunt, qui
        tenetur?
    </div>
</div>
</body>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/jspdf@latest/dist/jspdf.umd.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/html2canvas@1.0.0-rc.7/dist/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jspdf-html2canvas@latest/dist/jspdf-html2canvas.min.js"></script>

<!--pure jspdf-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.2/jspdf.debug.js"></script>

<script src="main.js"></script>
</html>
```